# Google Analytics - How to calculate CTR based on Event Actions using Total Events

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

For selected Event Label results are:
[image: Total Events]

How to present in custom report value of CTR [%] = (Total Events for Click) / (Total Events for Hit)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to perform calculations of this type within Google Analytics or Google Data Studio. You can divide one metric by another (such as Unique Events / Total Events), but not one dimension's metric value by another dimension's metric value.

If you need this on an ongoing basis, so it's worth some extra work to set up a report, you can do it in Google Sheets with the Google Analytics Add-On. The [add-on documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) will get you started. Your actual report would be in a different tab of the spreadsheet, where you can copy over data directly from the GA reports and also do whatever arithmetic is useful to you.